# How to set the Visibility rule for the Salesforce Custom Filed

Tags: custom-field, visibility

How to set up the visibility rule for the Salesforce Custom Field naming "Cable Provider"
I want to make the field appear only when the "Manufacturing Code" is "BUS". I couldn’t do it on the edit page of the Org. Please help as I am a beginner to SF.

**filename: Cable_Provider__c.field-meta.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Cable_Provider__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Cable Provider</label>
    <length>30</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</CustomField>
```

**FileName: Case.layout-meta.xml**

```xml
<layoutItems>
    <behavior>Edit</behavior>
    <field>Cable_Provider__c</field>
</layoutItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic form you can control the visibility of that field based on your criteria.

And I guess you can use xml of flexi page to see the changes.